# How to get view height? In a RecyclerView when view item haven't appeared

Tags: android-recyclerview

When I add a data to my adapter and send inserted notification.

Then I want scroll to the position which new added data, I cannot get view height after add it to data adapter.
I will use RecyclerView.SmoothScrollBy(0, addedView.getHeight());. Cause of RecyclerView.SmoothScrolltoPosition wasn't smooth when RecyclerView was full of screen.

I want to do scroll job when onBindViewHolder but I cannot get view height in this method.

So the question is how to get view height after add it to data adapter.

Comment: `mLinearLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition() ?`

Comment: I've found what I should to do, Implement the layoutManager.